# Format Exception - Catch and Try

Tags: c#

I want to test catching format exceptions, but the program crashes if I try to enter any words. How can I make my program catch Exceptions without crashing?

```
string words;
int[] number;
int i = 0;

while (true)
{
    Console.WriteLine("How many numbers would you like to enter? ");
    words = Console.ReadLine();

    if (isInteger(words))
    {
        number = new int[Convert.ToInt32(words)];
        Console.WriteLine("Please enter your numbers: ");

        for (i = 0; i < number.Length; ++i)
        {
            number[i] = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            isInteger(words);
        }
    }
}
```

`isInteger` method:

```
private static bool isInteger(string words)
{
    try
    {
         return true;
    }
    catch (FormatException)
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: `return true;` in `try` block will cause `catch` block never executed. You can check using `int.Parse(words)` inside try block which can throw `FormatException` if `words` is not numeric.

Comment: It says that all of the statements should return a value (  true, false etc)

Comment: `try { var number = int.Parse(words); return true; }` => if `words` is not numeric, it will throw `FormatException` and then `return false` executed. You can use `if (int.TryParse(words, out int number)) { return true; }` but it not throwing `FormatException`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to catch the exceptions thrown by the calls to `Convert` `Convert.ToInt32(words)` or `Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine())` they need to be wrapped in the try catch block.  Any catch only handles the exceptions that occur inside the preceding try. So, for example

```
try
{
  number = new int[Convert.ToInt32(words);
}
catch (FormatException ex)
{
  // Do something here ex is needed if you want to look at the exception
}
```

Or you could wrap it all in one try catch

```
try
{
  number = new int[Convert.ToInt32(words);
  Console.WriteLine("Please enter your numbers: ");

  for (i = 0; i < number.Length; ++i)
  {
    number[i] = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
    isInteger(words);
  }
}
catch (FormatException ex)
{
  // Do something here ex is needed if you want to look at the exception
}
```

`isInteger` will never have an exception to handle because all it does is return true which will never except.  If you want to handle an exception in a function, either the function has to make the call that will except, or be called in the catch block.